# Cloud 9 IDE dashboard not loading

Tags: cookies, proxy, cloud9-ide

it's some weeks, that with 3 different browsers (chrome dev, firefox, internet explorer) i can't load my dashboard,
the site is quite slow (internet connection is very good indeed) and after logon, the website go blank (or little light blue depends on the attempt)
and keep load for infinite time... after some minutes, it end to load, but totally blank.

i'm under a proxy if this could help to understand the problem.

windows XP
chrome dev (currently 20)
chrome stable
firefox 9
internet explorer 8

i tried deleting browsers cache/cookies ... (even in browser that i never tried with cloud9)
i tried with c9.io and cloud9ide.com, both same results.

some suggestion?
thanks

Comment: This is off topic, it should be in super user. <-- I know this comment is two years after last update.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem. I think it had to do with some updates they did recently that were not compatible with old projects you may have had in you account.

For some weird reason, I was able to get the dashboard to load on one machine (only). The fix for me was to download all my old projects, completely delete all projects and my account, then recreated it later and upload your downloaded projects.